# Dropwizard: 1.X - can I get cross-parameter method validation to work?

Tags: java, dropwizard, bean-validation

Annotation:

```java
@Target({METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, FIELD})
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = AtLeastOneNotNullValidator.class)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface AtLeastOneNotNull {

    String message () default "{com.validationError}";

    Class<?>[] groups () default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload () default {};

    String[] fieldNames();
}
```

Validator (currently always returns `false` on purpose):

```
@SupportedValidationTarget(ValidationTarget.PARAMETERS)
public class AtLeastOneNotNullValidator implements ConstraintValidator<AtLeastOneNotNull, String[]> {

    private String[] fieldNames;

    @Override
    public void initialize(AtLeastOneNotNull constraintAnnotation) {
        this.fieldNames = constraintAnnotation.fieldNames();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String[] value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Method:

```java
    // within some class
    @Valid
    @AtLeastOneNotNull(fieldNames = {"userName", "companyName"})
    private List<SomeObj> findAll(@Valid String userName, @Valid String companyName, String token) {...}
```

No matter what I can't seem to get this to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me by adding @Validated(org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;) before the class declaration.

e.g.

```
   @Service
   @Validated
   public class CourseService {
   ...
   }
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31705202)